# There is no 'save as' function on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I wanted to save Tableau as twbx format, but there is no save as option, only 'Save to Tableau Public As'.

My Tableu is tableau public. Is it possible for tableau public to save locally? and How do i save the work into twbx format?

Thank You

Comment: if the question has been answered, please accept it in order to mark the thread as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially correct.

There's no "save as" function.

Anyway, once you publish the workbook on your Tableau Public profile, then you can download it like all the other workbooks available for download.

That specific twbx file could be also used with Tableau Public desktop while you can't use .twbx files which are not published on Tableau Public.

Comment: oh my, i didnt notice there is a download button on the bottom right corner. Thanks